# Synchronizing folders between two servers

Tags: php, synchronization, rsync, fallback, mirroring

I have to realize a fallback solution (a auth system) for an external application. Therefore I have to keep the auth folder of my primary auth server syncronized with my fallback servers. The folder contains several .php files, .bin files and some others. Unfortunately I have no idea how I should realize a (for example hourly) syncronization of those folders to my fallback servers.

All servers use CPanel / WHM, maybe there is a solution for this or how can I keep them synced otherwise? I thought about a .php script which logs in via FTP and syncronizes them. I would put a cronjob then for this .php script. But I don't even know whether this is possible. If the primary server is offline it shouldn't affect my fallback servers in a negative way of course.

How should/can I realize this?

Comment: what exactly are you syncing? if its just files, could you deploy with git/CI?

Comment: git,svn,rsync,scp - choose one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leonel Atencio's suggestion of rsync is great.

Here is the rsync shell script that I use.  It is placed in a folder named `/publish` in my project.  The gist contains the rs_exclude.txt file the shell script mentions.

#### rsync.sh

```
# reverse the comments on the next two lines to do a dry run
#dryrun=--dry-run
dryrun=

c=--compress
exclude=--exclude-from=rs_exclude.txt
pg="--no-p --no-g"

#delete is dangerous - use caution.  I deleted 15 years worth of digital photos using rsync with delete turned on.
# reverse the comments on the next two lines to enable deleting
#delete=--delete
delete=

rsync_options=-Pav
rsync_local_path=../
rsync_server_string=user@example.com
rsync_server_path="/home/www.example.com"

# choose one.
#rsync $rsync_options $dryrun $delete $exclude $c $pg $rsync_local_path $rsync_server_string:$rsync_server_path

#how to specify an alternate port
#rsync -e "ssh -p 2220" $dryrun $delete $exclude $c $pg $rsync_local_path $rsync_server_string:$rsync_server_path
```

https://gist.github.com/treehousetim/2a7871f87fa53007f17e

### running via cron

[image: Cron]
[Source](http://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/)

Edit your crontab.

```
# crontab -e
```

Crontab entries are one per line.  The comment character is the pound (#) symbol. Use the following syntax for your cron entry.

These examples assume you placed your rsync.sh script in `~/rsync`
These examples will also create log files of the rsync output.

**Each Minute**

```
* * * * * ~/rsync/rsync.sh > ~/rsync/rsync.log
```

**Every 5 Minutes**

```
*/5 * * * * ~/rsync/rsync.sh > ~/rsync/rsync.log
```

Save your crontab and exit the editor.  You should see a message confirming your addition to the crontab.

Comment: Thank you both, going to try this.

Comment: Can you tell me how to run my rsync command periodacilly (or onchange), including typing my destionation's ssh password ofcourse? I try a small shell script, which uses inotify. But this didn't work because I want to sync a mounted folder.

Comment: to run it periodically use [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).   In order to log in automatically and not have to type a password each time use [ssh keys](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2)

Comment: A quick trip to google looking for notifiers that work on a mounted folder reveals that it's far more complicated (some mentioned running a process on the remote server that would forward change events to remote clients)  I'd set up cron to fire frequently - every few minutes would probably be okay since rsync is very fast.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use RSYNC, assuming you are not on a shared hosting plan.

> Rsync, which stands for "remote sync", is a remote and local file
>   synchronization tool. It uses an algorithm that minimizes the amount
>   of data copied by only moving the portions of files that have changed.

http://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/

For this to work, you need to have access to SFTP port on your server and of course, a linux terminal!.

Comment: rsync can also be used over ssh.  +1 for rsync.  I love it.

Comment: Can you tell me how to run my rsync command periodacilly (or onchange), including typing my destionation's ssh password ofcourse? I try a small shell script, which uses inotify. But this didn't work because I want to sync a mounted folder.